# NodejS-Magento Rest API

Tags: node.js, rest, magento

I am new to Magento and NodeJs. Can anyone please help to make connection between NodeJS  application and Magento Rest APIs through Oauth. It will be really great if anyone can provide me step by step procedure for the same.. thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Magento documentation is good place to start https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/bk-rest.html.

Also, it worth to check following projects on the GitHub

- https://github.com/fabacus/node-magento2
- https://github.com/DivanteLtd/magento2-rest-client
- https://github.com/troublediehard/magento-react-native